# Build failed in KMM project in iOS simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, build.gradle, kotlin-multiplatform

Working in Kotlin Multiplatform project with Cocoapods dependency.

These are the build output log

> Ld
> /Users/andrea/Folders/KMP/ComposeWeather/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/ComposeWeather.app/ComposeWeather
> normal (in target 'iosApp' from project 'iosApp')
> cd /Users/andrea/Folders/KMP/ComposeWeather/iosApp
> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang
> -Xlinker -reproducible -target x86_64-apple-ios14.1-simulator -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator17.2.sdk
> -O0 -L/Users/andrea/Folders/KMP/ComposeWeather/build/ios/EagerLinkingTBDs/Debug-iphonesimulator
> -L/Users/andrea/Folders/KMP/ComposeWeather/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator
> -F/Users/andrea/Folders/KMP/ComposeWeather/build/ios/EagerLinkingTBDs/Debug-iphonesimulator
> -F/Users/andrea/Folders/KMP/ComposeWeather/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator
> -F/Users/andrea/Folders/KMP/ComposeWeather/iosApp/../shared/build/xcode-frameworks/Debug/iphonesimulator17.2
> -F/Users/andrea/Folders/KMP/ComposeWeather/iosApp/../composeApp/build/xcode-frameworks/Debug/iphonesimulator17.2
> -filelist /Users/andrea/Folders/KMP/ComposeWeather/build/ios/iosApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/iosApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ComposeWeather.LinkFileList
> -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker /usr/lib/swift -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker
> @loader_path/Frameworks -dead_strip -Xlinker -object_path_lto -Xlinker
> /Users/andrea/Folders/KMP/ComposeWeather/build/ios/iosApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/iosApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ComposeWeather_lto.o
> -Xlinker -export_dynamic -Xlinker -no_deduplicate -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -fobjc-link-runtime -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphonesimulator
> -L/usr/lib/swift -Xlinker -add_ast_path -Xlinker /Users/andrea/Folders/KMP/ComposeWeather/build/ios/iosApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/iosApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ComposeWeather.swiftmodule
> -ObjC -lc++ -framework composeApp -framework composeApp -Xlinker -sectcreate -Xlinker __TEXT -Xlinker __entitlements -Xlinker /Users/andrea/Folders/KMP/ComposeWeather/build/ios/iosApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/iosApp.build/ComposeWeather.app-Simulated.xcent
> -Xlinker -sectcreate -Xlinker __TEXT -Xlinker __ents_der -Xlinker /Users/andrea/Folders/KMP/ComposeWeather/build/ios/iosApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/iosApp.build/ComposeWeather.app-Simulated.xcent.der
> -framework Pods_iosApp -Xlinker -no_adhoc_codesign -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/andrea/Folders/KMP/ComposeWeather/build/ios/iosApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/iosApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ComposeWeather_dependency_info.dat
> -o /Users/andrea/Folders/KMP/ComposeWeather/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/ComposeWeather.app/ComposeWeather
>
> ld: warning: search path
> '/Users/andrea/Folders/KMP/ComposeWeather/iosApp/../shared/build/xcode-frameworks/Debug/iphonesimulator17.2'
> not found
>
> ld: framework 'Pods_iosApp' not found clang: error: linker command
> failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
>
> ** BUILD FAILED **
>
> The following build commands failed:
>
> Ld
> /Users/andrea/Folders/KMP/ComposeWeather/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/ComposeWeather.app/ComposeWeather
> normal (in target 'iosApp' from project 'iosApp')
>
> (1 failure) warning: Run script build phase 'Compile Kotlin Framework'
> will be run during every build because it does not specify any
> outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to
> the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking
> "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target
> 'iosApp' from project 'iosApp')

The Cocoapods scripts in build.gradle.kts

```
cocoapods {
        version = "1.0.0"
        summary = "Some description for the Shared Module"
        homepage = "Link to the Shared Module homepage"
        ios.deploymentTarget = "16.0"
        podfile = project.file("../iosApp/Podfile")
        framework {
            baseName = "composeApp"
            isStatic = true
        }

        // Maps custom Xcode configuration to NativeBuildType
        xcodeConfigurationToNativeBuildType["CUSTOM_DEBUG"] = NativeBuildType.DEBUG
        xcodeConfigurationToNativeBuildType["CUSTOM_RELEASE"] = NativeBuildType.RELEASE
    }
```

Appreciate if there is any help or clue, how I can solve this.
Note : it works fine for Android simulator

Comment: btw the complete repo is https://github.com/andrea-liu87/compose-weather. 
XCode version is 15.2
Idk why I can't edit the question

Answer (score 0):

Well the error here:

**'/Users/andrea/Folders/KMP/ComposeWeather/iosApp/../shared/build/xcode-frameworks/Debug/iphonesimulator17.2' not found**

Can you check if you have the simulator device installed (the target device you are deploying to)?

And can you also check if you have **iOSX64** target set properly on your shared module's gradle file?

You should have something like this:

```
kotlin{

  iOSArm64()
  iOSX64()

  commonMain(){

  }


  val x64 = iOSX64 by getting
  val arm64 = iOSArm64 by getting

  iOSMain(){
      dependsOn(commonMain)
 
      // makes sure all iOSMain source sets are compiled into target folders
      x64.dependsOn(this)  
      arm64.dependsOn(this)
  }
}
```

With x64 devices you should only be able to target rosetta simulators.

For example: iPhone 14 (Rosetta).

With **simulatorArm64** you should be able to target non rosetta